# Understanding Linked Lists tutorial

Tags: c++

I'm reading the tutorials from [cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com) and I'm a bit stuck with their linked list example. The code is below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node {
  int x;
  node *next;
};

int main() {
  node *root;  
  node *conductor;

  root = new node;
  root->next = 0;
  (*root).x = 12;  // I was testing alt. syntax.
  conductor = root;

  if(conductor != 0) {
    while(conductor->next != 0) {
      cout << conductor->x;
      conductor = conductor->next;
    }
  }

  conductor->next = new node;
  conductor = conductor->next;
  conductor->next = 0;
  (*conductor).x = 42;

  cout << conductor->x;

  return 0;
}
```

In the example `root->next` is being set to `0`. `conductor` is then being set to the address of `root` which means the while loop will never be reached right?

I don't understand the purpose of the example if it's not demonstrating the use of a linked list (i.e. adding more nodes, and traversing through them).

Am I analyzing the code correctly?

Comment: might be better asked at <http://programmers.stackexchange.com/>

Comment: The while loop will be reached, because conductor == root and root != 0.

Comment: for your information, this example is basically C with streams. C++ would have a much better structure, using constructors and automatic memory handling.

Comment: I got the code from here http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson15.html ... I am just learning at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, in this example the while loop should be skipped as conductor->next will be 0 from the beginning.

This is probably a simple mistake and the author wants to show the way that a list is generally traversed through - and there his code is actually completely correct. My best guess is that he copy & pasted this code out of a (probably his own) LinkedList class and tried to assemble a quick example without testing it or thinking it through thoroughly. The way it works now, the while loop is basically meaningless since it doesn't do anything - but that probably wasn't the intention of the author.

Answer (score 0):

```
root = new node;   
root->next = 0;
```

Creates a new `node` & initializes the `next` pointer to `0`.

```
conductor = root;
```

sets `conductor` pointer to address of `root`

```
if(conductor != 0) 
 {     
     while(conductor->next != 0) 
     {     
         cout << conductor->x;      
         conductor = conductor->next;   
     } 
 }
```

In order to add a new node one needs to navigate to the end of the link list, the above while loop does that.

Probably, this sample code was quickly put together by assembling pieces from an existing link list code. 
This while loop is not really necessary if you know you have just one node in the link list. Probably, it was a part of the some function like `addNodeToList()` in original code, which would need to navigate to end of list before adding new node to the list.

Comment: But shouldn't next contain the address of another node?

Comment: @James: only if you want a longer list :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense at all

```
root = new node;
//then later
conductor = root;
if(conductor != 0) {
```

here `conductor` can't be null - the check is meaningless, then

```
while(conductor->next != 0) {
```

here `conductor` equals `root`, so `conductor->next` is null

```
conductor->next = new node;
```

And add to this that all created nodes are just leaked when the program ends. This sample doesn't demonstrate anything.

Comment: Here is the example http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson15.html ... I feel like I've wasted my time with that one. Do you know a good example of creating linked lists?

Comment: Here you have a bit of descriptive text: http://cplus.about.com/od/learningc/ss/pointers2.htm

Comment: @James Perno: Look for code that uses separate functions for separate operations. It could be "create empty list", "add node at the beginning", "delete after this node", etc. With such operations it's clear what pre- and post-conditions are and this will give you better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

> Conductor is then being set to the
>   address of root which means the while
>   loop will never be reached right?

If `root` is non`0` then `conductor` is also non`0`, So `while()` loop will be definitely reached.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example, although it's probably describing something, doesn't do anything productive in my eyes :). Since before the while loop **root** and **conductor** are pointing at the same thing and the **next** of that object contains **0**. So the while loop will never fire. After that we create a new node and let **next** point to it. Then we instead point **conductor** to the node and set it's **next** to **0**. This would result in a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

`next = 0` marks the end of the list, similar to a zero-terminated string. It is a convention with linked lists in general. As you populate the list, you move the zero-terminated `next` pointer forward (across the list). All other nodes have a valid `next` value pointing to the next node in the list.